# Site Usage Reports web User Interface not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

When we go to a subsite of a web application, we get the message:
"No data is available for this report. Usage analysis might have been enabled recently, or there might have been insufficient usage to report in any values for the report"

We have followed the instructions to configure the site usage reports on the farm and have checked to see whether the reports feature is activated etc. We do have the logs folder location at default path and have ensured the wss_adm groups have the appropriate permission. We also have logs turned on at the iis web app area.

This problem is farm wide and occurs on the different web applications we have in the farm.

so plz any help???

Answer (score 0):

the configure from:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262541%28office.12%29.aspx